# NXP LPC-Link 2 hangs when flashing and debug

Tags: embedded, jtag, nxp

im using a JTAG probe NXP LPC link 2 , with IAR Embedded workbench and procesor LPC1766.

for some reason when i compile and try to load either a debug or release firmware onto the LPC1766 , it works the first time ... then if i stop the debuger , recompile and try to load again , the loading process gets stuck at this point.

[image]

Then im forced to close the IDE , and unplug the usb cable of the probe , and relaunch the ide in order to work again.

Its very time consuming.
Any hints on how to improve this ?

note:
-The processor is connected to J7 on the probe
-probe is in swd mode

This is my debug configuration:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're going to have to be far more specific.  What hangs?  The programming application?  Windows?   The MCU?   Have you put the tool in its most verbose output mode?  Have you checked with the tool vendor?   Does the code run if you then power cycle the MCU without the JTAG connected?  The alleged promise of proprietary tools is that they just work; the problem is that when they do not, you have little recourse to understand why, verses something like openocd where you can actually debug the tool itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found it:

i changed the reset condition to "reset pin" , now it works every time !

Comment: Please accept your self-answer so that the system will consider the question resolved and not periodically churn it back up as if it is in need of attention